# Is there a way to filter file names by ~?

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to find all file names in a root directory that contain a ~ so they can be changed.

I have tried using the `escape character (-filter "`~" instead of -filter "~"), however when doing that it grabs nothing.

I have also tried putting the ~ in a string variable, but that also did not work, it just pulled the entire root folder again

I know there are  about 200 files that have ~ in their name in the test directory, so this should grab 200 files.

```
[string] $rootfolder = "C:\Documents\Powershell-Test",
[string] $folder = "",
[string] $subfolder = "",
#Place Illegal Character Here
[string] $illegalCharacter = "~",
#place replacement Phrase here
[string] $replacementPhrase = "",


$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $rootfolder -Recurse -Filter *$illegalCharacter*
```

I use the same script I used to find other unwanted characters. When I ran this script for # and &, it grabbed all the files with the character, remo and printed them to a csv file.

When I ran the ~, it grabbed every file in the root folder.

I did not include the code to print the file because that code is not altered when changing what is being searched for.

Comment: Since you are using `-Recurse`, you can use `-Include "*~*"` rather than `-Filter` to do this.

Comment: @AdminOfThings `-Recurse` + `-Include` makes for a _terrible_ combo, performance-wise

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen is grabbing everything and piping to `Where-Object` any better?

Comment: In this case, yes :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I just tried what you suggested. It still pull every file in the folder. I need it to only pull files with ~ in the file name. Any advice there?

Comment: @daustindev not sure what you refer to, I didn't suggest anything :)

Answer (score 2):

`-Filter` qualifies the path parameter. This means you need wildcards if you don't know the exact string name of target directory or file. If you don't know where the `~` exists in the file names, you need to use `*~*` when qualifying the path. Per [Matthias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen), `-Filter "*~*"` will not produce the desired result because `*~*` matches every single file with 8 or more characters in the name because PowerShell offloads filtering to Windows, and Windows applies the filter to both the real name and the 8dot3 name of the file system items.

The following will produce the desired result. Note this was tested on PowerShell v5.1.

```
$rootfolder = "C:\Documents\Powershell-Test"
$illegalCharacter = '~'
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $rootfolder -Recurse |
             Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*$IllegalCharacter*"}
```

Comment: `"*~*"` matches every single file with 8 or more characters in the name because PowerShell offloads filtering to Windows - and Windows applies the filter to both the real name and the 8dot3 name of the file system items, so for this to work you'd have to disable 8dot3 support :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, Thanks for that info. I updated the post.

Comment: I just tried the code you posted. It still pulled every file in the directory.  Is there a way to force powershell to recognize the ~ character as just a string and not representative of anything? I tried the ` escape character.

Comment: What version of PowerShell and OS are you running because this works for me without issues?

Comment: I am running PowerShell version 5.1.17134.858 on a machine running Windows 10 Enterprise x64.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the wildcards in the path works for me.  The -filter *~* matching short filenames thing doesn't happen in PS 6, so it appears to be a bug.

```
get-childitem -path $rootfolder\*$illegalCharacter* -recurse
```

It even matches the number in the short filename.

```
cmd /c dir /x

07/17/2019  02:19 PM                10 VERYLO~2.TXT verylongname.txt

ls . *2*

-a----        7/17/2019   2:19 PM             10 verylongname.txt
```

"get-childitem -filter" seems like something to be avoided, like ">".